# Cordova iOS plugins don't work

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova, plugins

I create an app with visual studio 2017.
I have install file, file tranfer, inappbroswer, device plugins.
On Android work the plugin, for example:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=yes');
window.open("http://www.google.it", "_system");
var folder = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
```

On iOs none of those plugins works.
Sample of a error:

```
plugin 'inappbrowser' not found or is not a cdvplugin. check your plugin mapping in config.xml
```

When I no recive that error, simply nothing happen.

Using google i check from xcode that the file of plugin CVDInAppBrowser.m is in project and in target membership and it's OK.
I check meta tag:
 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:">`
or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

I have included
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>`

I use Cordova 6.3.1
cordova-ios 4.2.0
cordova-android 5.2.1

I deploy on a updated iPad 4

Config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="~1.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />
  <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
  <engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
  <engine name="windows" spec="4.4.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="~2.0.19" src="https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.6" />
```

.

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

I use plugins always next document ready.

I've already tried:

- update cordova
- update ios
- remove and add ios and build/clean etc
- google the problem but nothing work

Comment: did you try removing and re-adding the plugins on a Mac before building?

Comment: @TrevorD do u mean from visual studio or from xcode? If you mean from xcode how do I do it?

Comment: @TrevorD I install again plugins but nothing change